# Configuring jest, wallabyjs in a rush monorepo

Tags: jestjs, monorepo, wallaby.js

I'm attempting to set up a monorepo using [rush](https://rushjs.io) for monorepo management, [jest](https://jestjs.io) as my test framework, and [wallabyjs](https://wallabyjs.com) as my test runner.  When I attempt to start wallaby, I get the error `[Error] Automatic Jest configuration error: Module jest-cli is not found in '.'.` in my wallaby console.

My understanding of rush and its monorepo approach is that the root does not have a package.json - just the actual libs/apps have a package.json file.  If this is the case, how do I add jest-cli at the root level?  I have jest-cli installed globally.

What do I need to do to get this running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the wallaby automatic configuration apparently wouldn't work in a monorepo.  I had to explicitly add a wallaby.js config file.  Details on the file are here: https://wallabyjs.com/docs/config/overview.html